# Trees / Graphs, How to represent Multiple parents and children?

Tags: graph, tree

I'm hoping you can help me out with some technical questions on graphs/trees.

I'm trying to display the creation of objects in systems.
It's really a tree structure.

---

It has some interesting requirements.

a)
One node can have many children.  Say 20.  Maybe more.
ie. one library can be used by many objects.

b)
A child node can have many parents.  Say up to 20.
ie.  many libraries are used by one procedure or object

c)
A particular node can appear in more than one place.
ie. a generic print, or logging function is called in many procedures

Note: This is just an -example- in tech terms I expect you will understand.
It is NOT the issue I need to model.  No need to discuss it.

---

As I've thought about it, I realized that it's not a simple binary tree, or a linked list.

1)
What kind of data structure could I save all the data in?

2)
How could I produce a graph of this in java?

3)
What is a free open source graphing software that could graph such a tree?
Such as Neo4j

Perhaps in formats:
- as a tree, with a root, trunk, branches, and leaves?
- Like the graphs you see now, depicting social networks, with the root node in the center?

4)
Any good websites, or tutorials on this subject?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/). It's old but it works. You'll have to invest a bit of time to learn how to use it though. Once you get there, it's just a matter of creating a `prefuse.data.Graph` object and fill in your nodes and their neighbors and then creating the visualization.

If you're open to other solution check out [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) - draw graph using javascript on SVG element in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really about objects, then maybe [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) can help. It's designed to generate graphs of object relationships. There are tons of free UML tools out there. I'd download one and see if you can shoehorn your application into it.

Answer (score 0):

[JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/) can represent your graph structure and can use [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) for visualisation.

For an example visualization, look at [this](http://www.jgrapht.org/visualizations.html).